# db.collection.update $set is not working

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using gv3.6.2 mongo db and using $set to-update a field and it just doesn't work and am clueless as to why?any pointers are appreciated?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient . 
from bson import ObjectId
import os,pymongo
dbuser = os.environ.get('user', '')
dbpass = os.environ.get('pwd', '')
uri = 'mongodb://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@machineip/data'.format(**locals())
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client.data
collection = db['test']
print db.version
db.collection.update(
                    { "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e2") },
                        { "$set": 
                            {
                                "status": "submission"
                            }
                    }
                )

Document:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e2"),
    "status" : "Submitting",
    "endRev" : "9531c3448d3f7713dc74c4b05d177ecf0c6e4df6",
    "chip" : "4364",
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of pymongo you are using?

Comment: @bro-grammer - am using 3.6.2 ,also I added a screen shot of how the document is structured

Comment: In pymongo version >=2.2 the import is `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`

Comment: Also you need to change `db.collection.update(...)` to `collection.update(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your update isn't working because of the match portion of your query:

```
{ "_id": "5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e2" }
```

That is searching for a document with a **string** `_id`. You must cast to an ObjectId in order for it to find the matching document and perform the update.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e2") }
```

Also be sure to include `from pymongo import ObjectId`.

Comment: I updated my answer with your suggestion,it did `not` work,also `from bson import ObjectId` is the right import

Comment: Could you print the result of the query (or the err)?

Comment: @J Livengood - There is no error,the script just runs...how to debug this?

Comment: am using 3.6.2 ,also I added a screen shot of how the document is structured

Comment: Try `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`. In unsuccessful, do `tempvar = db.collection.update...........` and print tempvar

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_many` to update more than one document. If you want to update one document use `update_one`.
Actually `update` is deprecated.

```
from bson import ObjectId
db.collection.update_many({"_id" : ObjectId("5a95a1c32a2e2e0025e6d6e2")}, {"status": "submission"})
```

I hope it helps.